# Iframing a responsive website source + dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm working on a custom site builder and have an iframe as the preview of the responsive website. To get the site to be 'zoomed out' so the site isn't in mobile size i'm using css scale and transform origin like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="iframePanel">
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
      <div class="intrinsic-container">
        <iframe id="display_frame" name="display_frame" class="frame" src="http://test.com" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/row-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#display_frame').iFrameResize(
        [
            {   
                log: true,
                checkOrigin: false
            }
        ]
    );

</script>

.intrinsic-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#iframePanel {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 16px #BEBEBE;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.50);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.50);
    -o-transform: scale(0.50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.50);
    transform: scale(0.50);
/*  width: 100%;*/
}
```

Since it's a site builder, certain sections can get hidden thus changing the height of the iframe. How can I get the height of the iframe and set it to the container? I'm trying to use this iFrame Resizer (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer), but I think the scale css i'm using on the iframe is messing it up. The plugin runs and then I have a ton of extra white space on the bottom. I have tried all of their 'heightCalculationMethod' and they all have the same result. Is there a way I can write my own custom height calculation if i'm using this css scale?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by saying I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish as far as restrictions go for the way you want to display your 'preview site'.

Below is something that I wrote years ago that dynamically resizes an iframe when you change the window size. I did it using 2 files because I dynamically change a lot that you don't see with PHP that you do not need, but you can combine to use only 1 file if needed. Obviously the variables I have in here are specific to my site and the size I needed. Also, since this was many moons ago, the code is not the best and probably can be much more modular if you need it to be. Also, I did this with native JavaScript only and no jQuery. Also, I removed all extraneous script and CSS so it is more readable.

**File 1**

```
<!---------- START HTML ------------->
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>

    <body onresize="return setSizeOnChange();">

        <div id="page_container">

            <div id="content">

                <table id="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th id="table_left_top"></th>
                        <th id="table_center_top"></th>
                        <th id="table_right_top"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="table_left_middle"></td>
                        <?php

                            include("/var/www/html/secured/content/home_content.php");

                        ?>
                        <td id="table_right_middle"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="table_left_bottom"></td>
                        <td id="table_center_bottom"></td>
                        <td id="table_right_bottom"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function setSizeOnChange()
            {
                window.setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    var iframe = document.getElementById('home_content_iframe');
                    var bottom_menu = document.getElementById('bottom_menu');
                    var leftmenu = document.getElementById('leftmenu');

                    var window_height = $(window).height();
                    var window_width = $(window).width();

                    var height = window_height - 86;//113 //73  // - bottom_menu.offsetHeight
                    var width = window_width - leftmenu.offsetWidth - 60;//60

                    if(leftmenu.offsetWidth == 0)
                    {
                        iframe.width = width;
                        iframe.height = height;
                    }else
                    {
                        iframe.width = width + 25;
                        iframe.height = height + 17;
                    }
                    return true;

                }, 90);
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
<!---------- END HTML ------------->
```

**File 2**

```
<!---------- START HTML ------------->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body onload="return setSize();">

        <td id="table_center_middle">
            <iframe src="../content/home_content_iframe.php" id="home_content_iframe" name="home_content_iframe"></iframe>';
        </td>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function setSize()
            {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('home_content_iframe');

                var window_height = $(window).height();
                var window_width = $(window).width();

                var height = window_height - 86;//113
                var width = window_width - 260;//260

                iframe.height = height;
                iframe.width = width;

                return true;
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
<!---------- END HTML ------------->
```

I hope this helps. If not, then I misunderstood and would love to help, but I would need some more details on what your requirements are.